# symfony 5, css, js , images not loaded in PROD

Tags: php, symfony4

**Hi there!**

i've just deploy my symfony5 website on hostinger.
but css, js, images are not loaded in PROD.

**Notice :** Everything is working well in DEV

**i have my css , js ,images file whitin my public folder**

Comment: are your paths for these resources relative? or hard-coded to the staging path?

Comment: Already fixed @AdamSmooch

Comment: Great! In that case you may want to consider deleting your question, or share your own answer, if you think others may benefit from how you got in/out of this issue.